# ngrx effect - two http api in same effect

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have the below effect to update a part of an object using the `update` api (this api returns an id of the object), then i get the whole object using the `findById` api to which i pass the result of the api update as parameter, the problem is that the first time i do the update the `findById` api returns the the object without the update, knowing that the update is done

```
@Effect()
updateScopeCoverage$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<networksActions.PatchScopeCoverage>(networksActions.NetworkActionTypes.PATCH_SCOPE_COVERAGE),
    map(action => action.payload),
    exhaustMap(scopeCoverage => this.apiNetwork.update({ updateScopeCoverageRequest: scopeCoverage }).pipe(
        switchMap(id => this.apiNetwork.findById({ externalId: id }).pipe(
            map((network: Network) => new networksActions.PatchSuccess({
                id: network.externalId,
                changes: network
            })),
        )),
        catchError(err => {
            alert(err.message);
            return of(new networksActions.Failure({ concern: 'PATCH', error: err }));
        })
    ))
);


findById(args: { externalId: string }): Observable<models.Network> {
        const path = `/networks/v1.0/${args.externalId}`;
        return this.http.get<models.Network>(`${this.domain}${path}`);
}
```

Comment: have you tried wirh MergeMap?

Comment: Please share source code of this.apiNetwork.findById too, because the effect is fine. if this.apiNetwork.update returns an expected `id` there's nothing to change and you need to check `apiNetwork`.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi no, how can i used ?

Comment: @satanTime, i shared the code.

Comment: aha, looks simple too :) do you use database replication on the backend? and what does `mapNetwork` do?

Comment: @satanTime i removed mapNetwork, i used postgresql on the backend.

Comment: If I understand right - the backend returns old data, is it correct? because the effect looks good. it sends an update request, waits for the response then sends findById, waits for it and dispatches the PatchSuccess action. The sequence is correct. I would console.log what backend returns and if it returns old data - it means there's cache or replication of the backend. For example try to put `delay(1000)` before `switchMap(id => findById`, if it works then 100% the issue with backend.

Comment: Have you found the issue?

Comment: @satanTime you are right, the problem is in backend, i add delay(100), it works fine, thnx.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it helped, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right - the backend returns old data, is it correct? because the effect looks good. it sends an update request, waits for the response then sends findById, waits for it and dispatches the PatchSuccess action. The sequence is correct. I would console.log what backend returns and if it returns old data - it means there's cache or replication of the backend. For example try to put delay(1000) before switchMap(id => findById, if it works then 100% the issue with backend.